# Changing opacity of a rectangle

Tags: python, tkinter

How do i change the opacity/transparency of a black rectangle in python tkinter.

```
canvas.create_rectangle (200, 200, 600, 600, fill="black")
```

Above is what i used to create the box. I looked at attributes i could use but could not find any. I also played with `.setOpacity(0.5)` as i saw this being used somewhere else but it did not work.

I have looked at different examples and they either change the opacity for images using the PIL module or change the opacity in different languages which i am unfamiliar with.

Comment: I don't think you can mess with alpha on a Canvas.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can change alpha(Transparency) on a canvas. But you can use `stipple` on it to cover it with a bitmap, so you kinda get the same effect but not exact.

Try this line.

`canvas.create_rectangle (200, 200, 600, 600, fill="black",stipple='gray50')`

Comment: You can use [`'gray75'`, `'gray50'`, `'gray25'` and `'gray12'`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/bitmaps.html)

Comment: because they are predefined @CallumTwig. You can learn more about that [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/bitmaps.html). And if you really want to customize then you can go for adding your own bitmaps too.